Has Java ever done in the past what they are planning to do with the removal of sun.misc.Unsafe, which is to break backwards compatibility?
I'm aware that the Java platform has historically emphasized maintaining backwards compatibility, even across major versions. This has been one of the cornerstones of its wide adoption in enterprise environments. However, I recently came across discussions about the removal of sun.misc.Unsafe coming on Java 25-26, a class that, while undocumented and technically internal, has been widely used by developers for years to access low-level functionalities.
This leads me to wonder: Will I have to provide two versions of my application: one pre-remove and another one post-remove? It surprises me very much that the newest version of Java won't be able to run my old code. Why not just leave it there and let the community migrate to the new FFM API at its own pace?
How is the community planning on coping with this breaking change? Has such a change ever happened in the past, or that is going to be the first time?
Note that I'm not saying that I want to support old Java versions forever. What I'm saying is that it would suck for a new JVM not to be able to run an application that I have been running since forever. When that happens I'm left with two bad choices: 1) Never migrate to the new JVM 2) Wait for the vendor to provide a newer version of the application. Is there a third choice I'm not seeing?

My personal opinion is that it's long past time.  There should be no packages left in the code base that still refer to Sun.  Migrate to the new JVM.   It's worth it.

While not a removal, the iteration order of HashMap and HashSet has changed between releases, "breaking" code that wrongly assumed it could rely on the order.  I consider relying on that order as foolish as relying on sun.misc.Unsafe.

“Why not just leave it there” — because: JEP draft: Integrity by Default “Developers expect that their code and data is protected against use that is unwanted or unwise. The Java Platform, however, contains unsafe APIs that can undermine this expectation, thereby damaging the correctness, maintainability, scalability, security, and performance of applications. Going forward, we will restrict the unsafe APIs so that, by default, libraries, frameworks, and tools cannot use them. Application authors will have the ability to override this default.”

Deprecation for removal is nothing new. It's been around since Java 9. In the Javadoc for any Java version, you can hit the "Deprecated" link at the top of the page to see the list of deprecated stuff, starting with the "Terminally Deprecated Elements" or "For Removal" list of stuff they're planning to remove.
For example, here's that page for Java 11, with a long list of stuff to remove, and here's that list for Java 22. Just picking an example, we can see that java.lang.Compiler shows up in the first list and not the second, and looking through the java.lang docs for Java 22, we can see that it's been removed.
People deal with these removals the same way they deal with the same situation when any library or language removes things: rewrite their code to not use the stuff that got removed. In the case of sun.misc.Unsafe, that means migrating to java.lang.invoke.VarHandle and java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment.

And that means having two versions of your codebase and binaries in parallel, one for pre-remove and another one for post-remove. Is that a true statement? Java26 will simply not run old code. I haven't come across that before.

@PhillipBorge: If you want to support old Java versions forever, old enough that no acceptable substitutes for the deprecated APIs exist, then yes. In that case, you'd probably end up writing a compatibility layer that tries to abstract over the differences, to minimize the amount of code that needs to be different for different Java versions.

I'm not saying that I want to support old Java versions forever. What I'm saying is that it would suck for a new JVM not to be able to run an application that i have been running since forever. When that happens I'm left with two bad choices: 1) Never migrate to the new JVM 2) Wait for the vendor to provide a newer version of the application. Is there a third choice?

Hack the application yourself. I don't recommend it though.

@PhillipBorge: Since Java 9, applications are supposed to be bundled with their own Java runtime. An application that hasn't been updated for Java 26 wouldn't be shipped with Java 26. It'd be shipped with a version it's compatible with.

@user2357112 Not trying to be a dick or anything, just sharing my experience, which is of course unique to myself, industry, etc. But It does not feel that what you said happened, in other words, the corporate environment maintain their own JVMs and migrate whenever they feel like doing it, to a new version or even vendor (Azul). Perhaps for desktop applications what you said would make more sense but for enterprise applications I'm not so sure, in other words, jar and jvm are very separate entities. If they should be or not is a different story.

@user2357112 that's an opinion not an official statement. The JDK does provide tools for embedding the JDK since Java 9 but it is not mandated.

@PhillipBorge that was uncalled for. You were given technical options that you requested. If they are not what you would like to hear is nobody's fault.

@PhillipBorge: It sounds like you're frustrated. You had very high compatibility expectations of Java, that Java doesn't meet, and now you have to deal with the problems you thought Java would protect you from. But there's not really much we can do to help. Even if this had been the very first time Java deprecated anything for removal, it wouldn't change how you need to deal with it. And the options for dealing with it are pretty much what you'd expect.

The sun.misc.Unsafe thing is a bad example of breaking the compatibility "promise", because, given it was in the sun.* namespace, third parties should never have used it to begin with: it was not actually part of the public API of Java, and there never was a promise on its stability or anything (some Java implementations didn't even have it, as far as I'm aware).

I think that can be addressed with an interface and the classpath.
Create an interface. The old implementation using sun.misc.Unsafe will be compiled and provided with the application jar. The other new one using FFM will be provided in a separate patch jar.
Both implementations will have the same name and package, so the application will load the one that appears first in the classpath.
So for clients running the older JVM, you simply do not need to provide this patch jar. For clients running the new JVM you do.

Ok but I'm talking from the perspective of the client. The client will be dependent on the vendor to provide the patched jar to him...

There's no need to use a separate patch JAR, use a multi-release JAR file. Inside the JAR there is a default implementation using sun.misc.Unsafe, and for newer versions an implementation that uses FFM. See https://openjdk.org/jeps/238, https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jar/jar.html and/or https://www.baeldung.com/java-multi-release-jar.
